# How to check if there are spaces inside editText and fill them programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to check if there is a space or not between letters and add a space if there is or not, remove if there are to many. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

What I am currently doing checking for postcode however I want to add spaces if there is no spaces e.g. M11SS make it M1 1SS and delete starting spaces and ending spaces

```
if (a.isEmpty(txtJobPostcode)) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter a postcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
if(txtJobPostcode.getText().toString().matches("^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}$")){
    Log.d("NOTICE", String.valueOf(txtJobPostcode));
} 
else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter a valid postcode", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: sounds like something you'll need a grammar, a parser and a formatter

Comment: You could just modify your regex to allow \s* at the beginning and end. Make the space optional and enclose the section before and after with group capture. Then build your string with group1+space+group2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to consider: `TextWatcher` class in Android sdk.

You can find the documentation by the link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Also you can try some libs(**solution from the box**) to save your time:

https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask

https://github.com/reinaldoarrosi/MaskedEditText

Answer (score 0):

String myString = txtJobPostcode.getText().toString().trim() - will remove beginning and end spaces.
Then if you know for sure where the space needs to be, you can check the letter in that specific position if it's not equal to " " then replace letter using StringBuilder, i.e.

```
String letter = myString.substring(1,2)
if (!letter.equals(" ")) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(myString);
    sb.insert(1, " ")
    myString = sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: setCharAt will overwrite the character at that position, you want to use insert